# count++ on Cordova Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I need the ajax work synchronously and only display `console.log('Downloads finalized!');` when all downloads are finished, but the `count++` is not working within the `fileTransfer.download` function. Why?

My code:

```
function getdata()
{
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var path = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    jQuery.getJSON(MyJSONData, function( data ) {
        var count = 0;
        jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
            fileTransfer.download(
                MyFileURL,
                path+"data/images/"+key+".jpg",
                function(theFile) {
                    console.log('Saved');
                    count++;
                }, null
            );
        });
        while(1)
        {
            if(count == Object.keys(data).length)
            {
                console.log('Downloads finalized!');
                break;
            }
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('Error');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the ajax work synchronously

No, you need to understand how to use callback functions.

```js
function getdata() {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var path = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
  jQuery.getJSON(MyJSONData, function(data) {
    var count = 0;
    jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
      fileTransfer.download(
        MyFileURL,
        path + "data/images/" + key + ".jpg",
        function(theFile) {
          console.log('Saved');
          count++;
          if (count == Object.keys(data).length) {
            console.log('Downloads finalized!');
          }
        }, null
      );
    });
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log('Error');
  });
}
```